Using a double integral to find the CDF of the standard Cauchy distribution
This question overlaps with the second question here. Blitzstein and Hwang's "Introduction to probability" says: "Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$, and let $T = X / Y$."
Following an explanation of $F_T(t) = P(X \leq t|Y|)$ (which the above link goes into) is some simplification of a double integral:
\begin{align}
F_T(t) &= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2 / 2}\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{t|Y|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2 / 2}\ \mathrm{d}x\bigg)\ \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(t|y|)\ \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(ty)\ \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align}
How do you explain the last equation? My only idea has been to split the left-hand side into $[-\infty, 0]$ and $[0, \infty]$.

Assuming you're integrating over $(-\infty,\infty)$, that would be the approach, to exploit that $|y|$ term. This would give
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I} &:= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(t|y|)\ \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(-ty)\ \mathrm{d}y + \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(ty)\ \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}$$
In the left integral, perform this change of variables:
$$\begin{align*}
\eta &:= -y \\
\mathrm{d} \eta &= - \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}$$
This gives
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{J} &:= \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(-ty)\ \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \int_\infty^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(-\eta)^2 / 2}\Phi(t\eta)\ (-\mathrm{d}\eta)\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\eta^2 / 2}\Phi(t\eta)\  \mathrm{d}\eta 
\end{align*}$$
Compare to the right integral of $\mathcal{I}$. Hence,
$$
\mathcal{I} = 2 \mathcal{J} =\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty   e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(ty)\ \mathrm{d}y =\sqrt{ \frac 2 \pi } \int_0^\infty  e^{-y^2 / 2}\Phi(ty)\ \mathrm{d}y
$$
as desired.
